# "annehmen" means both "assume" and "presume"

Tags: meaning, english-to-german, meaning-in-context

Consider these two English words:

- assume
- presume

Similar they may be, there is still a subtle difference between the two, namely the action of "presuming" involving more certainty. Now, German dictionaries list these two words as rightful definitions of the word "annehmen". I wonder if one can use "annehmen" to mean assume/presume regardless of the degree of certainty in German.

Comment: It may clarify things a bit to quote my dictionary (American Heritage) on the meanings of these words: "To _presume_ is to suppose that something is justified, sound, or possible in the absence of proof to the contrary." "To _assume_ is to accept something as true without proof or on inconclusive grounds." In everyday language I'd use them pretty much interchangeably though.

Comment: Just from the fact that as a native speaker of German whose English vocabulary usually isn’t bad I have no clear idea of the meaning of “presume” I assume(?) that the distinction doesn’t exist in German in the same way.

Comment: @RDBury So "presume" means "consider true without proof" and "assume" means "consider true without proof"? The meaning "consider possible" for "presume" would be even weaker.

Comment: @Dr.Doom You should explain the subtle difference between "assume" and "presume", otherwise the question should be closed because "Needs expertise in a language other than German"

Comment: @RalfFriedl - I'm a native English speaker and as you might guess I had to look up the difference myself. (And I had to look in several places; my old paper dictionary is my last resort.) I gather though that "presume" is the result of circumstantial evidence. If you see a man and a woman check into a hotel with two kids and a lot of luggage you presume they are married. You can "assume" with no evidence at all, circumstantial or otherwise.

Comment: If you consider something true for no apparent reason, I would use the word "guess" and not "assume". I think even most guesses are based on some hints.

Answer (score 4):

The literal translation of the German verb *annehmen* is *to take on* or *to take to yourself* which doesn't make much sense in English, but best can described as "to accept something that is given to you":

> Ich werde dieses beschädigte Paket nicht **annehmen.**
> I will not **accept** this damaged package.
>
> Robert passte den Ball zu Heinz, der ihn aus der Luft **annahm** und ein Tor schoss, das die Heimmannschaft 1:0 in Führung brachte.
> Robert passed the ball to Heinz, who **took** it out of the air and kicked a goal to give the home team a 1-0 lead.
>
> Erwin hat unsere Einladung **angenommen.**
> Erwin has **accepted** our invitation.
>
> Laura hat eine Stelle in einem Krankenhaus **angenommen.**
> Laura has **taken** a job in a hospital.

The last sentence shows, that *"given to you"* is not always necessary. You can also *annehmen* things that you have chosen for yourself. Here are more examples:

> Susanne hat geheiratet und hat dabei den Nachnamen ihres Mannes **angenommen.**
> Susanne got married and **took** her husband's surname.
>
> Einige der Flüchtlinge haben den christlichen Glauben **angenommen.**
> Some of the refugees have **adopted** the Christian faith.

The last sentence shows, that you can take, accept or adopt a faith or also a believe. So, it seems, as if we German native speakers could also say this:

> Ich habe die Vermutung **angenommen**, dass Sandra zu Ihrer Mutter gefahren ist.
> I have **adopted** the assumption that Sandra had gone to her mother.

But we don't. It is a grammatical correct sentence, and it will also be understood, but is sounds as clumsy as the English translation. You do not adopt assumptions. You assume. So, in fact we say this:

> Ich **nehme an,** dass Sandra zu Ihrer Mutter gefahren ist.
> I **assume** that Sandra had gone to her mother.

But still the last two sentences have the same meaning: There is an assumption, and we made it our own. We accepted/adopted/took this assumption. And the meaning, that *"annehmen"* has in this last sentence is the most often used meaning for this verb, and for that reason, most dictionaries list "to assume" as the first meaning of "annehmen".

---

This meaning of accepting an assumption is the main meaning of the english verb *"to assume"* and also one of the meanings of *"to presume".* The difference is just, that *to presume* means, that the degree of possible correctness is higher.

> I **presume** she won't mind if we start without her.
> Ich **nehme an,** sie hat nichts dagegen, wenn wir ohne sie anfangen.
>
> He **presumed** that the train would be late due to the bad weather.
> Er **nahm an,** dass der Zug wegen des schlechten Wetters Verspätung hat.
>
> We'll **presume** the event is still on unless we hear otherwise.
> Wir **nehmen an,** dass die Veranstaltung stattfindet, sofern wir nichts Gegenteiliges hören.

But these sentences are still all about conjectures and speculations, and therefore *annehmen* is the best German translation. But *to presume* also has a meaning that is different form guessing that something is true. *To presume* can also mean, that there is a condition, that must be true to make other things possible. So, we are not guessing wether something is correct or not, but we talk about premisses for dependencies and conclusions, and then it would be wrong to translate is as *annehmen.* The better choice is *voraussetzen* (literally: *"to set ahead"* or *"to set beforehand"*):

> Our plan **presumes** that the market conditions will remain stable for the next year.
> Unser Plan **setzt voraus,** dass die Marktbedingungen im nächsten Jahr stabil bleiben.

We do not assume that the market conditions are stable nor do we assume that they are unstable. Instead we say: If they are stable, our plan will work. If not, then probably not.

> To solve this problem, we must **presume** full cooperation from all departments.
> Um dieses Problem zu lösen, müssen wir die volle Zusammenarbeit aller Abteilungen **voraussetzen.**

We do not know whether we get full cooperation from all departments. We assume neither that it is the case, not that it's not. Instead we say that full cooperation is necessary condition.

> The software's effectiveness **presumes** a certain level of user expertise.
> Die Effektivität der Software **setzt** ein gewisses Maß an Benutzerkompetenz **voraus.**

Again, we do not talk about how high the users expertise really is. Instead we say: If their experience is high, then the software will be effective. (If it's low, the software will probably be ineffective.)

Comment: This is a very thorough approach at analyzing the meaning, but I disagree with some parts of your reasoning: 'The last sentence shows, that *"given to you"* is not always necessary. You can also annehmen things that you have chosen for yourself.' - sure, Laura has chosen to apply for the position, but given that you cannot unilaterally take on a position in a company without the employer hiring you, the job is arguably just as much given to Laura as she has chosen to take it. So, that meaning is definitely in there. ...

Comment: ... "We do not assume that the market conditions are stable" - I think we do, for what else is the meaning of "Unser Plan setzt voraus, dass ..." than "Damit unser Plan funktioniert, **nehmen wir an**, dass ..."? Of course, we can insist that "Unser Plan setzt voraus" is a more concise and elegant way of expressing the thought, but ultimately, the statement boils down to making a statement while pointing out which **assumptions** need to be true for the statement to apply.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die Argumentation setzt voraus, dass die Voraussetzungen für das Gelingen eines Plans beim Erstellen dieses Plans als wahrscheinlich angenommen werden müssen. Das ist aber nicht immer so ... beispielsweise nicht bei Notfallplänen. Dabei werden Gewisse Scenarien angenommen - und die Pläne nur bei Erfüllen der Voraussetzungen aktiviert.

Comment: @planetmaker: Ich bin ehrlich gesagt nicht sicher, was du mit "Die Argumentation" meinst - meine? Oder Huberts? Jedenfalls belegt die Verwendung von "annehmen" in "Dabei werden Gewisse Scenarien angenommen" sehr schön, worauf ich hinauswollte.

Answer (score 1):

Words in one language almost never have an exact equivalent in another language, and this is no exception. Neither "assume" nor "presume" is exactly equivalent to "annehmen". There are cases where "annehmen" can be translated as "assume", cases where it can be translated as "presume", cases where both are acceptable, and cases where neither would be correct. Conversely, there are cases where "assume" or "presume" can be translated as "annehmen", and cases where they can't.

Comment: Less an answer than a comment, but it was worth saying. You need to know the context and exact intended meaning before you can say what word to use when translating to another language. Sometimes there is no direct translation at all and you have to rephrase entirely to get the message across.

Answer (score 0):

- to assume — annehmen, vermuten
- to presume — annehmen, voraussetzen

That latter *voraussetzen* is what you are after. It's not a mere assumption but a prerequisite for all what follows.

> *Dr. Livingstone, I presume.*

Dr. Livingstone, setze ich voraus.

Comment: The "I presume" is no longer used, at least in the US. It's also seen as somewhat humorous or ironic; per Wikipedia "The words are famous because of their perceived humour, Livingstone being the only other white person for hundreds of miles, along with Stanley's clumsy attempt at appearing dignified in the bush of Africa by making a formal greeting one might expect to hear in the confines of an upper-class London club." Fun fact, there is little evidence that Stanley actually said that.

Comment: "Dr. Livingstone, setze ich voraus" sounds very strange to me. I would definitely put "nehme ich an" there.